# ¿como puedo invocar un metodo a otra clase?

Tags: java

buenos dias/tardes/noches, estoy intentando hacer un codigo que cree la clase triangulos, un metodo dibujar y dicho metodo invocarlo en una clase Figuras pero al intentar hacerlo no me da el resultado, cuando lo compiloen las clases separadas me dice que
Figuras.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
dibujar();
^
symbol:   method dibujar()
location: class Figuras
1 error
no se a que se puede referir, o tal vez no invoce el
metodo de una forma eficiente,espero y me puedan ayudar, gracias!

```
    //archivo 1 Triangulos.java
    public class Triangulos {

     public static void dibujar(){
       System.out.println("dibujando triangulo");     
       System.out.println("      * ");
       System.out.println("    *   *");
       System.out.println("  *      *");
       System.out.println("  ********");  
     }
     }

    //archivo 2 Figuras.java
    public class Figuras{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       dibujar();
     }

     }
```

Comment: Debes indicar el nombre de la clase: Triangulos.dibujar();

Comment: aaaaaa ya veo, lo hice pero me aparece el error de que debo invocar el public static void main en la clase triangulos, y no se donde invocarlo ya que si lo invoco dentro o fuera de la funcion dibujar me aparece error

Answer (score 2):

El detalle es que no reconoce la función dibujar, puesto que esta es parte de la clase Triangulos. En este caso tendrías que invocarlo de la siguiente manera

```
public class Figuras {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Triangulos.dibujar();
    }
}
```

Comment: Debes importar la clase, si es que no se encuentran ambas en el mismo paquete.

Comment: @Hill comprendo, lo hice pero al intentar compilar(despues de que solucione el error del metodo) me aparece que el public static void main no lo invoce en la clase triangulos, pero no se en que parte invocarla ya que si lo invoco adentro o fuera del metodo dibujar me aparece error, sabes como solucionarlo?

Comment: @LeonardoAlbertoAlvaradoAgui recuerda que en Java solo debe existir un método main(), según tu problema es en la clase Figuras que debes de tener el método main(). ¿Qué error te aparece?

Comment: @Hill de echo no, el error se origina en la clase triangulos, es este: Error: Main method not found in class Triangulos, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args) pero segun yo no hace falta poner un main a la clase triangulos y si tuviese que poner el main en la clase triangulos no sabria en donde(este error me aparecio despues de corregir el de mi pregunta)

Comment: @LeonardoAlbertoAlvaradoAgui verifica que ambas clases estén en el mismo paquete.

Comment: @Hill ya funciono, use el compilador online jdoodle y creo que ese no se ocupa importar las clases(o eso creo), lo que hice fue que declare Figuras como el "compilador inicial"(make it startfile) y lo compile y si agarro, o como seria para importar las clases, ¿seria asi? import nombredelaclase

Answer (score 1):

Si estás trabajando con NetBeans o Eclipse o cualquier otro IDE debería generarte la clase sin problemas pero para que quede más claro (y en caso de que uses solo un editor de texto y compiles manualmente) tú codigo debería verse así:

## Clase Figuras

```
package nombrePaquete;

public class Figuras {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Triangulos.dibujar();
    }
}
```

## Clase Triangulos

```
package nombrePaquete;

public class Triangulos {

     public static void dibujar(){
         System.out.println("dibujando triangulo");     
         System.out.println("      * ");
         System.out.println("    *   *");
         System.out.println("  *      *");
         System.out.println("  ********");  
     }
}
```

Comment: aaaa ya comprendo, entonces lo aplicare, muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de ayudarme, lo aprecio mucho y me ha ayudado a comprender mas cosas de este lenguaje, gracias!!